# Is there a List<T> in .NET 2 that raises events when the list changes?

Tags: .net, collections, observablecollection

I have used `ObservableCollection<T>` in the past, but that seems to belong to WPF and therefore .NET 3.

And if there isn't what would be the appropriate interface for that? `INotifyPropertyChanged` seems not to be a very good fit for collections, while `INotifyCollectionChanged` is again only supported in .NET 3 and higher.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The [Collection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) exposes virtual InsertItem, RemoveItem, SetItem and ClearItems methods that you could override and add your own events triggers to.

(Just a possible alternative to the BindingList<T>)

Answer (score 0):

All of the collections in the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5) are designed to be able to raise events when an item is added, inserted, removed, or when the collection is cleared or otherwise changed. It provides a more robust interface for dealing with these changes than being held strictly to a list of objects, but also works with dictionaries, hash tables, priority queues, persistently sorted lists, etc.